# recaptcha validation returns invalid even after valid entry

Tags: php, joomla, recaptcha

I have activated the keys for my recaptcha and then implemented it using following code:

form:

```
<?php
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onInit','dynamic_recaptcha_1');
?>

<form ............>
.............
<div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field">
</form>
```

Then in controller I am validating the captcha as below:

```
 $capatcha = JRequest::getVar('recaptcha_response_field', 'POST');

 JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
 $dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
 $res = $dispatcher->trigger('onCheckAnswer',$capatcha);

 if(!$res[0]){
    $errors['captcha'] = "Invalid Captcha";
 }
```

The problem is that even if i supply correct captcha value, I get the Invalid Captcha notice.

Plus I must say I am not convinced by the approach of having integrated recaptcha in my component because I cannot modify/customize anything here `<div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1"></div>`. So, I would be happy if somebody could give me a better idea to integrate recaptcha in joomla component. I found out that my method of captcha integration do not work if I am not connected to internet. So, I wanna use the libcaptcha.php so that atleast captcha is displayed even if I am offline.

Comment: what does `var_dump( $res )` give you?

Comment: Why are you not just setting the keys in the plugin? 
ALso if you want to use something besides recaptcha just make a new plugin along the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

Now its working fine. the problem was with the `<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field">`. i don't know why i have used that. i deleted the line for that field and now its working ok.

but i am not convinced yet with the recaptcha integration because i've no control over it. i would appreciate if someone could give me a better idea to implement captcha in component. note that i am not using jform.